# NullPointerException on ViewDragHelper.getTouchSlop()

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

I have an issue, a strange one that i cannot replicate but i see the issue exists on a lot of users. The crash is caught in Crashlitycs. The issue is:

> Fatal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException
>   Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.support.v4.widget.ViewDragHelper.getTouchSlop()' on a null object reference

Currently i have set the support library to 28.0.0.

I have no idea on what to try next because i don't understand where this bug comes from and i cannot reproduce it

```
final SUPPORT_LIBRARY_VERSION = '28.0.0'

// Support
implementation "com.android.support:design:$SUPPORT_LIBRARY_VERSION"
implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$SUPPORT_LIBRARY_VERSION"
implementation "com.android.support:cardview-v7:$SUPPORT_LIBRARY_VERSION"
implementation "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:$SUPPORT_LIBRARY_VERSION"
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.1'
implementation "com.android.support:exifinterface:$SUPPORT_LIBRARY_VERSION"
implementation "com.android.support:support-media-compat:$SUPPORT_LIBRARY_VERSION"
implementation "com.android.support:support-v4:$SUPPORT_LIBRARY_VERSION"
```

Here is my Logcat

```
       at android.support.design.widget.BottomSheetBehavior.onTouchEvent(BottomSheetBehavior.java:350)
       at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.performIntercept(CoordinatorLayout.java:476)
       at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onTouchEvent(CoordinatorLayout.java:527)
       at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:9390)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2549)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2240)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2555)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2254)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2555)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2254)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2555)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2254)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2555)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2254)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2555)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2254)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2555)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2254)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2555)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2254)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2555)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2254)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2555)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2254)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2555)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2254)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2555)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2254)
       at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2461)
       at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1777)
       at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2865)
       at android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchTouchEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:69)
       at android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchTouchEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:69)
       at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2422)
       at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:9610)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4447)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:4313)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3847)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3900)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3866)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3992)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3874)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4049)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3847)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3900)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3866)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3874)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3847)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6146)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:6120)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6081)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6262)
       at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:192)
       at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(MessageQueue.java)
       at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:330)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5621)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:794)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:684)

--

Fatal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.support.v4.widget.ViewDragHelper.getTouchSlop()' on a null object reference
       at android.support.design.widget.BottomSheetBehavior.onTouchEvent(BottomSheetBehavior.java:350)
       at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.performIntercept(CoordinatorLayout.java:476)
       at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onTouchEvent(CoordinatorLayout.java:527)
       at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:9390)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2549)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2240)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2555)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2254)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2555)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2254)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2555)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2254)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2555)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2254)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2555)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2254)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2555)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2254)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2555)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2254)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2555)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2254)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2555)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2254)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2555)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2254)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2555)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2254)
       at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2461)
       at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1777)
       at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2865)
       at android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchTouchEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:69)
       at android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchTouchEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:69)
       at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2422)
       at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:9610)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4447)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:4313)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3847)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3900)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3866)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3992)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3874)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4049)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3847)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3900)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3866)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3874)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3847)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6146)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:6120)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6081)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6262)
       at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:192)
       at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(MessageQueue.java)
       at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:330)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5621)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:794)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:684)

#0. Crashed: main
       at android.support.design.widget.BottomSheetBehavior.onTouchEvent(BottomSheetBehavior.java:350)
       at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.performIntercept(CoordinatorLayout.java:476)
       at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onTouchEvent(CoordinatorLayout.java:527)
       at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:9390)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2549)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2240)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2555)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2254)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2555)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2254)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2555)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2254)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2555)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2254)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2555)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2254)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2555)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2254)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2555)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2254)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2555)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2254)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2555)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2254)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2555)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2254)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2555)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2254)
       at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2461)
       at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1777)
       at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2865)
       at android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchTouchEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:69)
       at android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchTouchEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:69)
       at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2422)
       at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:9610)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4447)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:4313)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3847)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3900)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3866)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3992)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3874)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4049)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3847)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3900)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3866)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3874)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3847)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6146)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:6120)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6081)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6262)
       at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:192)
       at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(MessageQueue.java)
       at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:330)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5621)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:794)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:684)
```

Currently i extend `BottomSheetDialogFragment` for a lot of fragments (well, almost all of them)

Comment: Note to potential close voters: I don't believe the "What is a NullPointerException?" duplicate applies in this case as it's a problem with the internal classes of the Android SDK. There doesn't appear to be any direct references to OP's app within the stacktrace.

Comment: Guessing by the call to `BottomSheetBehavior` in the stacktrace, are you using any instances of `BottomSheet` anywhere in your app? If so, could you try dragging it and seeing what happens?

Comment: @MichaelDodd Yes, i do use it in the app. A lot actually. I extend ```BottomSheetDialogFragment``` for a lot of fragments. I cannot replicate it, i tried dragging, clicking, closing, etc..., nothing worked, i cannot replicate it but i can see that some percentages of users do have this issue

Answer (score 0):

Checking back in the source code the line that used to read:

```
return action == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE
        && scroll != null
        && !ignoreEvents
        && state != STATE_DRAGGING
        && !parent.isPointInChildBounds(scroll, (int) event.getX(), (int) event.getY())
        && Math.abs(initialY - event.getY()) > viewDragHelper.getTouchSlop();
  }
```

Appears to read in later versions:

```
 return action == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE
        && scroll != null
        && !ignoreEvents
        && state != STATE_DRAGGING
        && !parent.isPointInChildBounds(scroll, (int) event.getX(), (int) event.getY())
        && viewDragHelper != null
        && Math.abs(initialY - event.getY()) > viewDragHelper.getTouchSlop();
  }
```

Seems like it should be fixed. Though some other functions seem to clear the viewDragHelper value out so it might be hard to reproduce generally.

In some versions it seems like you could could get a nullpointer error if you performed a touch move before the onLayoutChild() got called. It seems like that might be hard to do. But, doesn't explicitly check for it.

Apparently it was *supposed* to be fixed, but I don't see an explicit check in the source and their reproduction steps might help you anyway.

https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/issues/43

> "This can occur on older/slower devices by spamming touch events to
>   the bottom sheet whilst the layout is being constructed."